# Firebase dynamic links admin generation or user genaration

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I would like to use firebase dynamic links for sharing posts in my app via a link.

I found out that the firebase admin SDK can't generate dynamic links. So that leaves a question: should each user generate a dynamic link each time they want to share a post via link?

If there are 10k posts, a lot of links will be generated.
Having a link like https://myApp.app.link/postID would be more efficient because everybody could use the same URL to share.

Is this possible or should each user generate a personal share link?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest) that you can use to generate Dynamic Links too. It sounds like you're looking to use that.

If the Admin SDK were to add support for Dynamic Links, it will likely be a fairly thin wrapper around that REST API.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. So it's possible to use it within a cloud function that triggers with a firestore doc creation?